# Como mandar um dado com o "setResult" de uma não activity para uma activity?

Tags: android

Tenho uma classe com um dialog que não é uma activity e o resultado deste dialog preciso atualizar na activity. Para fazer isso estou passando a Activity via construtor para o dialog, mas não funcionou. Alguém sabe como e se é possível fazer isso? Agradeço desde já.

Minha tentativa: `act.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);`

Na verdade eu não preciso nem mandar um dado para Activity, porque eu recupero do dado na Activity via banco, o que eu preciso é apenas saber se cliquei em um botao do dialog para assim buscar o dado do banco na minha Activity.

Comment: Poste o código da classe dialog.

Comment: O meu dialog é uma classe java pura apenas com esta linha do setResult, não tem nada de mais.

Comment: Não é legal acoplar as coisas assim. Talvez você possa usar uma coisa parecida com o que é recomendado para fazer `Fragment`s comunicarem-se com `Activity`s. Dê uma olhada nisso: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html